# Self-information, one event half as likely than another event conveys twice the amount of information?

Tags: probability, information-theory

I was [reading](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~bengioy/dlbook/prob.html) the following:

> "If one event is half as likely as another, then learning about the
>   former event shouldconvey twice as much information as the latter"

I know it should be easy to verify, but I just wanted to confirm with the community, that statement is false, right?

---

This is what I have:

Let b half as likely as a. Then:

$$\frac{P_X(a)}{2} = P_X(b)$$

So we should have according to the comment:

$$I(b) = 2I(a) = I(a) + I(a)$$

So lets apply the definition of $I(x) = -\log(P_X(x))$

$I(b) = -\log(\frac{P_X(a)}{2}) = -\log(1/2) + -\log(P_X(a))$

$I(b) = 1 + I(a)$

Which implies that it only added **one** more bit of information rather than adding one addition $I(a)$ units of information (i.e. doubling $I(a)$)

This makes me belief either there must be a incredibly smart trick to make this work, or I am wrong or I did a super embarrassing mistake or the statement was wrongly expressed.

Comment: In the text, it seems to me the statement about "twice as much information" occurs before "information" is quantitatively defined. I'm not sure what the statement even means in that context. Perhaps it was an informal statement, not a mathematical one (though I'm still unsure what the point was).

Comment: it does seem if this is what they mean by information in question, that you would need $P_{X}(a)^{2}=P_{X}(b)$ to get twice the amount of information

Comment: Actually it should say if one event is half as likely as another then it gives us one bit more information to know its outcome. This holds true in @leonbloy's example, in which we get 0 bits of information from learning event B and one bit from learning event A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we need more context. By itself, and using the common definition of information, the statement is false. For example, take: $P(A)=1/2$, and $P(B)=1$. The amount of information of event $B$ is zero. It makes no sense to say that $A$ gives usa twice information than that.